# How to filter values from 3 different models in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 classes and i want to filter them based on criteria taken form 3 classes. I am very new to django and especially model. Need your help. 
Student, group and nondemandgroup are tables in my Db.

```
class Students():
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    surname=models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Group20():
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    studentss=models.ManyToManyField(Students)
    math=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
    english=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)

class Nondemandgroup():
      name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
      studentss=models.ManyToManyField(Students)
      acting=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)  
      cooking=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
```

i want to get list of student who's final grade is met by fowlloing criteria:

```
final_grade = group20.objects.filter(math__gt=60, ((math+english+acting)/3)__gt=70)
```

`acting` is within `nondemandgroup` class so my final_grade doesn't work it says `no such column as acting`.

How to to make acting column work ? I tried Foreign key but it does not work and gives an error.

Or should i create a new model and filter within it where i will create foreign keys of 3 models ?

I am quite confused as i am very new to Django and models are confusing. Explored web however in my case i misunderstand smth and the formula does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go step by step. We want students matching the a given criteria.

1. First thing we see wrong is student is not connected to group in any way. So let's connect the students with groups

   ```
   from django.db import models

   class Student(models.Model):
       name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
       surname=models.CharField(max_length=200)

   class Group20(models.Model):
       student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
       math=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
       english=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)

   class Nondemandgroup(models.Model):
       student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
       acting=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)  
       cooking=models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=1000)
   ```
2. Now let's come to the part calculating the final grade

   Lets get all user's from group20 model who have more than 60 in math. We also need the math and english to calculate average score along with acting. So let's get that value as well.

   ```
   group20_objs = Group20.objects.filter(math__gt=60).values_list('student__name', 'math', 'english')
   ```

   This will give value in the following format

   ```
   [("studentA", "math_score_of_A", "english_score_of_A"), ...]
   [("Chantel", "100", "100"), ("Chantel1", "90", "85"),..]
   ```

   Now lets get the students who's average of math, english and acting is above 70.

   ```
   final_students = []
   for item in group20_objs:
       student_name, math_score, english_score = item
       # Get acting score for user
       # Hoping student will have record here as well
       acting_score = Nondemandgroup.objects.filter(student__name=student_name).first(). acting
       if (acting_score + math_score + english_score)/3 >= 70:
           final_students.append(student_name)
   ```

Now final_students list will contains students names with grades higher than 70. Do try to mix up the models if you want.

Also i recommend going through [django models docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/) for a better understanding

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213084/discussion-on-answer-by-kashyap-kn-how-to-filter-values-from-3-different-models).